# Redirecting to a Page in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007, moss

I have a custom WebPart with an asp.net button.The functionality is to update a list and redirect to a page.It works fine when the user has contribute access but when a user with read access clicks on button instead of redirecting it sits on the same page or redirects to access denied page.I am using the below code to redirect.
SPUtility.Redirect(homePageUrl, SPRedirectFlags.Default, HttpContext.Current);
The homePageUrl defined above is a property on the webpart.

Thanks
Rama

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are running into the issue where SharePoint steps in when an Unauthorized Access attempt happens, aborts the thread and sends your user to the access denied page.

What you need to do is *temporarily* disable this behavior.

```
spWeb.Site.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;
```

So that your exception handling can catch the error.